# [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass data from a Collection View Controller to a Table View Controller, but when I thought everything is ok this problem appears.. **unrecognized selector sent to instance** My code is this:

**ViewController.m (Collection View Controller)**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ColViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
// Private member varibles
NSArray *_arrayOfImages;
NSArray *_arrayOfNames;

// Array de ingredientes
NSArray *_arrayOfCeviche;
NSArray *_arrayOfTacacho;
NSArray *_arrayOfAnticucho;
NSArray *_arrayOfPapita;
NSArray *_arrayOfParihuela;
NSArray *_arrayOfLomo;

NSArray *_arrayOfIngredients;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Array que contiene los titulos
_arrayOfNames = @[@"Anticucho", @"Arroz Chaufa", @"Cebiche", @"Pachamanca", @"Papa a la Huancaina", @"Parihuela", @"Picante de cuy", @"Tacacho con cecina", @"Pollo a la brasa", @"Lomo saltado"];

// Array que contiene las imagenes
_arrayOfImages = @[@"Anticucho.jpg", @"chaufa.jpg", @"ceviche.jpg", @"pachamanca.jpg", @"papita.jpg", @"parihuela.jpg", @"cuy.jpg", @"tacacho.jpg", @"brasa.jpg", @"lomo.jpg"];

// Arrays que de los ingredientes
_arrayOfCeviche = @[@"Quesito", @"Limon", @"Choclito", @"Cocinita", @"La lechesita", @"La miradita", @"La weuabdita", @"La cagada", @"Ptm Toy Jodido XD", @"Que emoción", @"Wiiiiiii"];

_arrayOfLomo = @[@"Que novedada", @"jajajaja que buena", @"Lukita", @"losisisisi", @"maniserio", @"joder", @"joselet", @"lskadlkdl", @"bah"];

_arrayOfPapita = @[@"que buena!", @"csm!!", @"que genio!", @"novedades", @"que rico!!", @"coger delicisioso", @"Mffffff"];

_arrayOfParihuela = @[@"Un culaso", @"Chambon", @"Noveades", @"que hacer", @"asu macho", @"Espero que este bien", @"Así es la vida la chamba", @"Debo aprender mas!!"];

_arrayOfTacacho = @[@"Tacachin", @"Lalilinnn", @"Masinisn", @"Joder", @"Ojojoojojo", @"Lista hermosa!"];

_arrayOfAnticucho = @[@"Me encanta Objective-c", @"Hermosisimo", @"Me encanta xcode!", @"Que hermoso es esto", @"Debe ser un chambon total", @"jajajaja novedades", @"Lol supremo"];


 ***NSArray that contains all the arrays***
_arrayOfIngredients = @[_arrayOfCeviche, _arrayOfLomo, arrayOfAnticucho, _arrayOfParihuela, _arrayOfTacacho, _arrayOfPapita];

}
```

**And my method to pass the data from my collection view to the table view**

```
  // Method to pass data from a view to another view
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.Titulos = [_arrayOfIngredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
  }
}
```

**My DetailViewController.h (Table View Controller)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Titulos;

@end
```

**My DetailViewController.m (Table View Controller)**

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

***Xcode tell me this line is the problem...***
cell.textLabel.text = self.Titulos;

return cell;
}
```

**What is wrong with my code???** U.u

Comment: It means NSArray does not recognize the "length" method.  Either try "count" or switch from passing an NSArray to pass an NSString instead.

Comment: [NSArray has no `length` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Comment: (Hint: All that exception gorp you ignored is quite valuable, if you take the time to study it.  It tells you, eg, the exact line where the exception occurred, the type of object you were dealing with (NSArray), and the method being invoked ("length")).

Comment: (And if you bother to include that exception information in your question, and identify the line in error, you will make folks here much happier and much less inclined to downvote your question.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice :) I am new in iOS development and stackoverflow :) Next time i will do that :)!

Answer (score 4):

```
dvc.Titulos = [_arrayOfIngredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

if `_arrayOfIngredients` is an NSArray containing multiple NSArray objects, then you are passing an array into the **Titulos** object.

**Titulos** is an NSString so when a UILabel tries to access the `- length` property on the NSString a crash will occur as **Titulos** is an NSArray and not a NSString.

---

On your DetailViewController, I am assuming you want to pass in a sub-array from your _arrayOfIngredients.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *Titulos;

@end
```

Then you would have to configure your DetailViewController just like your ViewController but using the **Titulos** array.

Comment: Ohhhhh i see and what property should i look for to fix my problem? Or what i should look for or do?

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` doesn't respond to `length`, it responds to `count`. In the following line:

```
dvc.Titulos = [_arrayOfIngredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

You are passing an `NSArray` to a property that takes an `NSString`, so it at some point tries to get the length of the string, and instead calls the `length` method on an `NSArray` object, which doesn't respond do it, so it crashes.

Comment: Ohhhhh i see and what property should i look for to fix my problem? Or what i should look for or do?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with that value. You need to examine your program logic. As it is right now, `Titulos` is set to one of those arrays that you have defined above. What is it that you're actually wanting `Titulos` to be set to? That's the question you need to ask yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Check code:

```
for (int j=0; j<enumKeyReferenceArray.count; j++) {
  NSString *attri =[enumKeyReferenceArray valueForKey:@"BeltCondition"];      
}
```

An Issue was i was forgot to tell compiler from which i index element i needed.

Correct line should be:

```
NSString *attri =[enumKeyReferenceArray[j] valueForKey:@"BeltCondition"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an NSArray *dataArray to populate the tableView

What cause me problem is I use

```
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:anotherArray];
```

What I should do is

```
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:anotherArray]
```

So in your case, you should check what is contained within your dataArray

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was the data coming through API 
Data is :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Order listed successfully.",
    "data": [
        {
            "order_id": "9",
            "restaurant_name": "Demo Restaurant",
            "payment_token": "Test162R25892",
            "payment_status": "Approved",
            "subtotal": "480.00",
            "final_amount": "561.00",
            "vat": "57.00",
            "service_fee": "24.00",
            "delivery_fee": "0.00",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "customer_type": "member",
            "created": "2016-02-28 12:17:21",
            "order_status": "complete"
        }
    ]
}
```

and after converting it through NSJSONSerialization to NSDictionary it is

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            created = "2016-02-28 12:17:21";
            "customer_type" = member;
            "delivery_fee" = "0.00";
            discount = "0.00";
            "final_amount" = "561.00";
            "order_id" = 9;
            "order_status" = complete;
            "payment_status" = Approved;
            "payment_token" = Test162R25892;
            "restaurant_name" = "Demo Restaurant";
            "service_fee" = "24.00";
            subtotal = "480.00";
            vat = "57.00";
        }
    );
    message = "Order listed successfully.";
    status = 1;
}
```

And I just miss the [ brackets in `JSON` and ( in Dict, inside the data and parsed it like

`lblDate.text = [[dict valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"created"]`

and exception occurred because I tried to send an array value to label text. Just look the data carefully you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was problem with one of pods. Fixed with `pod update`.